# How to avoid a script finishing in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to learn Common Lisp, and found a simple webserver sample:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sbcl --script
;;; The following lines added by ql:add-to-init-file:
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))

(ql:quickload "cl-who")
(ql:quickload "hunchentoot")
(ql:quickload "parenscript")

(defpackage :vote
             (:use :cl :cl-who :hunchentoot :parenscript))

(in-package :vote)

(hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 8080))

(hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (say-yo :uri "/yo") (name)
  (setf (hunchentoot:content-type*) "text/plain")
  (format nil "Hey~@[ ~A~]!" name))
```

I'm running it with `--script` so I can iterate over the code and keep testing it.

The problem is - the script finishes right after launching the server, so I cannot test it.

**How could I make the program keep running until I `CTRL+D`/`CTRL+C` it?**

I *could* use something like `loop` and `sleep`, but it would be too cumbersome - ie, an active wait.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to iterate and test if you run it in the REPL? If you don't want to do that, I suppose the best option is to have it wait for input (as in `(format t "Press enter to quit") (read-line)`).

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to use <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, you can use **--load** instead of **--script** to load your file.  After the file is loaded, you get dropped into a REPL, from which you can use <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to quit.

While that may be workable, it might also make sense to consider a timer with a default parameter that can be overridden on the command line, so that the system shuts down after some expiration time.  Otherwise, you could inadvertently leave a web server running.